# 'How to become what you are' supposing Foucault is right about the body?

Tags: nietzsche, foucault

The phrase is the subtitle of Ecce Homo. You can a [short essay](https://philarchive.org/archive/FOUNGH) by Foucault, on Nietzsche, free of charge; it's also in his *essential works: aesthetics*, appearing originally in a book dedicated to Hyppolite. p153

> We believe, in any event, that the body obeys the exclusive laws of
>   physiology and that it escapes the influence of history, but this too
>   is false. The body is molded by a great many distinct regimes; it is
>   broken down by the rhythms of work, rest, and holidays; it is poisoned
>   by food or values, through eating habits or moral laws; it constructs
>   resistances. “ Effective ” history differs from traditional
>   history in being without constants. Nothing in man — not even his body — is sufficiently stable to serve as the basis for self-recognition
>   or for understanding other men.

Maybe it's just a crass misunderstanding, but I thought that Nietzsche felt his audience were innately disposed toward him because of their physiology. Then what is a higher type? Are these peculiar "great men", doers of great things, either made by the contingent processes of history, or innately of that type?

One answer I had is that, *since Nietzsche*, someone is either freed by his critique of Christian morality, or (virtuously) burdened by it, and that's what these two thinkers mean. But I'm not sure that's a good answer!